# Slow memory climb until crash in the GPU

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, shader, gpu

I'm displaying a grid of particle clouds using shaders. Every time a user clicks a cloud, that cloud disappears and a new one takes its place. The curious thing is that the memory usage in the GPU climbs every time a new cloud replaces an old one - regardless of whether that new cloud is larger or smaller (and the buffer sizes always stay the same - the unused points are simply displayed offscreen with no color). After less than 10 clicks the GPU maxes out and crashes.

Here is my physics shader where the new positions are updated - I pass in the new position values for the new cloud by updating certain values in the the `tOffsets` texture. After that are my two (vert and frag) visual effects shaders. Can you see my efficiency issue? Or could this be a garbage collection matter? - Thanks in advance!

**Physics Shader (frag only):**

```
// Physics shader: This shader handles the calculations to move the various points. The position values are rendered out to at texture that is passed to the next pair of shaders that add the sprites and opacity.

// the tPositions sampler is added to this shader by Three.js's GPUCompute script
uniform sampler2D tOffsets; 
uniform sampler2D tGridPositionsAndSeeds;
uniform sampler2D tSelectionFactors;
uniform float uPerMotifBufferDimension;
uniform float uTime;
uniform float uXOffW;

...noise functions omitted for brevity...

void main() {

        vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;

        vec4 offsets = texture2D( tOffsets, uv ).xyzw;
        float alphaMass = offsets.z;
        float cellIndex = offsets.w;


        if (cellIndex >= 0.0) { // this point will be rendered on screen

            float damping = 0.98;

            float texelSize = 1.0 / uPerMotifBufferDimension;
            vec2 perMotifUV = vec2( mod(cellIndex, uPerMotifBufferDimension)*texelSize, floor(cellIndex / uPerMotifBufferDimension)*texelSize );
            perMotifUV += vec2(0.5*texelSize);

            vec4 selectionFactors = texture2D( tSelectionFactors, perMotifUV ).xyzw;
            float swapState = selectionFactors.x;
            vec4 gridPosition = texture2D( tGridPositionsAndSeeds, perMotifUV ).xyzw;
            vec2 noiseSeed = gridPosition.zw;
            vec4 nowPos;
            vec2 velocity;

            nowPos = texture2D( tPositions, uv ).xyzw;
            velocity = vec2(nowPos.z, nowPos.w);

            if ( swapState == 0.0 ) { // if no new position values are ready to be swapped in for this point
                nowPos = texture2D( tPositions, uv ).xyzw;
                velocity = vec2(nowPos.z, nowPos.w);
            } else { // if swapState == 1, this means new position values are ready to be swapped in for this point
                nowPos = vec4( -(uTime) + offsets.x, offsets.y, 0.0, 0.0 );
                velocity = vec2(0.0, 0.0);
            }

            ...physics calculations omitted for brevity...

            vec2 newPosition = vec2(nowPos.x - velocity.x, nowPos.y - velocity.y);

            // Write new position out to a texture for processing in the visual effects shader
            gl_FragColor = vec4(newPosition.x, newPosition.y, velocity.x, velocity.y);

        } else { // this point will not be rendered on screen
            // Write new position out off screen (all -1 cellIndexes have off-screen offset values)
            gl_FragColor = vec4( offsets.x, offsets.y, 0.0, 0.0);
        }
```

From the physics shader the `tPositions` texture with the points' new movements is rendered out and passed to the visual effects shaders:

**Visual Effects Shader (vert):**

```
uniform sampler2D tPositions; // passed in from the Physics Shader
uniform sampler2D tSelectionFactors;
uniform float uPerMotifBufferDimension;
uniform sampler2D uTextureSheet;
uniform float uPointSize;
uniform float uTextureCoordSizeX;
uniform float uTextureCoordSizeY;

attribute float aTextureIndex;
attribute float aAlpha;
attribute float aCellIndex;

varying float vCellIndex;
varying vec2 vTextureCoords;
varying vec2 vTextureSize;
varying float vAlpha;
varying vec3 vColor;

...omitted noise functions for brevity...

void main() {

        vec4 tmpPos = texture2D( tPositions, position.xy );
        vec2 pos = tmpPos.xy;
        vec2 vel = tmpPos.zw;

        vCellIndex = aCellIndex;

        if (vCellIndex >= 0.0) { // this point will be rendered onscreen

            float texelSize = 1.0 / uPerMotifBufferDimension;
            vec2 perMotifUV = vec2( mod(aCellIndex, uPerMotifBufferDimension)*texelSize, floor(aCellIndex / uPerMotifBufferDimension)*texelSize );
            perMotifUV += vec2(0.5*texelSize);

            vec4 selectionFactors = texture2D( tSelectionFactors, perMotifUV ).xyzw;
            float aSelectedMotif = selectionFactors.x;
            float aColor = selectionFactors.y;
            float fadeFactor = selectionFactors.z;

            vTextureCoords = vec2( aTextureIndex * uTextureCoordSizeX, 0 );
            vTextureSize = vec2( uTextureCoordSizeX, uTextureCoordSizeY );

            vAlpha = aAlpha * fadeFactor;

            vColor = vec3( 1.0, aColor, 1.0 );

            gl_PointSize = uPointSize;

        } else { // this point will not be rendered onscreen
            vAlpha = 0.0;
            vColor = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            gl_PointSize = 0.0;
        }
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( pos.x, pos.y, position.z, 1.0 );
    }
```

**Visual Effects Shader (frag):**

```
uniform sampler2D tPositions;
    uniform sampler2D uTextureSheet;

    varying float vCellIndex;
    varying vec2 vTextureCoords;
    varying vec2 vTextureSize;
    varying float vAlpha;
    varying vec3 vColor;

    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = vec4( vColor, vAlpha );

        if (vCellIndex >= 0.0) { // this point will be rendered onscreen, so add the texture
            vec2 realTexCoord = vTextureCoords + ( gl_PointCoord * vTextureSize );
            gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * texture2D( uTextureSheet, realTexCoord );
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with the shaders they are irrelevant. You will need to show your Javascript code. But my guess is you are creating new textures each iteration and not destroying the old one. `gl.deleteTexture(textureHandle);` or however it is done in three.js (consult the documentation on deleting textures)

Comment: @Blindman67 - Ah, interesting. Thanks, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: @Blindman67 - Ha! Brilliant. That was exactly the problem. If you write up your answer, I'll accept it. The way to trigger what you recommended was to call `textureHandle.dispose();` in Three.js just before creating the new texture. Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Blindman67's comment above, I sorted out the problem. It had nothing to do with the shaders. In the Javascript (Three.js) I needed to signal the GPU to delete old textures before adding the updated ones.

Everytime I update a texture (most of mine are DataTextures) I need to call `dispose()` on the existing texture before creating and updating the new one, like so:

```
var textureHandle; // holds a reference to the current texture uniform value

textureHandle.dispose(); // ** deallocates GPU memory **
textureHandle = new THREE.DataTexture( textureData, dimension, dimension, THREE.RGBAFormat, THREE.FloatType );
textureHandle.needsUpdate = true;
uniforms.textureHandle.value = textureHandle;
```